# std::thread and std::cin.get

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a Global Variable called DebugConsole. It creates a console using Alloc Console and redirects std::cout and std::cin.

Thing is, when the console spawns, everything is fine. When I use std::cin.get() though, it blocks and the rest of my application is un-clickable. So I decided to thread std::cin.get(). When you press a key, the console closes just fine. The problem comes in when I uncheck the box. The thread cannot join because std::cin.get() is blocking it from moving. Thus I have to type first before it responds. This causes my whole application to freeze up.

I'm trying to make it so that when you press any key, it exits my console OR when you un-check the box, it closes my console.

```
if (ButtonChecked)
{
    std::cout<<"To close this window: \nRemove the checkmark from the Extract Box OR Press Any Key..\n"<<std::flush;

    DebugConsole.StartThread([window]{  //create an std::thread and run the lambda in it.
        std::cin.get();
        DebugConsole.StopThread();  //join the thread.
        DebugConsole(false, false);  //close the console.
        UncheckBox(DebugBox);
    });
}
else
{
     DebugConsole.StopThread(); //basically just joins the thread..
     UncheckBox(DebugBox);
}
```

The code that is the problem is above. Any idea how I can achieve it?

Comment: Your new thread tries to join itself.

Comment: Is that a problem? How else would the thread stop :S I also tried cin.peek.

Comment: Yes it's a problem. Think about it. The thread will block waiting for itself to finish, which will never happen until it returns from the join, which won't happen until it returns from the join, which won't happen ... deadlock. Joining does not stop the thread, it just waits for it to stop.

Comment: Also, how would the following lines (`DebugConsole(false, false); UncheckBox(DebugBox);`) run if the thread has already been joined i.e. stopped running?

Comment: I use this: void Debug::StopThread()
{
    try{if (DetachedThread) {this->Thread.detach();} else {this->Thread.join();}}
    catch (...){}
}

The false, false doesn't matter. It will automatically FreeConsole().

Comment: Ahh.. Damn. Need to actually stop the thread. :l But there is no Stop in std::thread.

Answer (score 1):

The main thread (after DebugConsole.StartThread() function call) should do a join with the thread - of course, it would need to know the thread ID, so you probably need `threadid = DebugConsole.StartThread(...);`  to make it work.

Comment: But the main thread is doing a join in the else-statement. It cannot join though because std::cin.get() blocks the thread from receiving the join command. OR it joins but still requires me to type..

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) & 1` instead of std::cin.get() and std::cin.peek().

All the other code was fine. It's just cin.get and peek wouldn't stop blocking. It was blocking my thread from joining/detaching because it kept waiting on user input.